# Setting Column Type Based on Column Value in Separate Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I'm new to R, so it would be much appreciated if I could get some pointers for this problem I'm having!

So I am currently writing a function with several inputs, two of them being separate data frames. One data frame is what I call the "*Master List*" and the other is the "*Data Source*." For example, here are two fake data frames that would go into this function:

***The Master List:***

| Data Frame Name | Column Name Needed | Set Column Type As: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pancake Data | How many eaten | dbl |
| Pancake Data | Flavor of Pancake | chr |
| Pancake Data | Preferred Flavor | chr |
| Pancake Data | Time of year | chr |
| Pancake Data | Flavors Ordered Based on Time of Year | dbl |
| Dessert Data | How many eaten | dbl |
| Dessert Data | Cake or Pie | chr |
| Dessert Data | Cookies or Brownies | chr |
| Dessert Data | Time of year | chr |
| Dessert Data | Quantity Eaten Based on Time of Year | dbl |

Where the "Data Frame Name" column is the name of the data frame that I will be inputting into the function.

"Column Name Needed" defines which columns I want to select and pull from the Data Source.

"Set Column Type As" is what type I want to force the columns in the *Data Source* to be. (For example, I want to force the Time of Year column to be a chr instead of a Date)

***The Data Source:***

(I'll go ahead and use Pancake Data instead of Dessert Data as the example data frame here)

| Restaurant Name | Cost | How many eaten | Flavor of Pancake | Preferred Flavor | Time of year | Time it takes to cook | Flavors Ordered Based on Time of Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *chr* | *dbl* | *dbl* | *chr* | *chr* | *Date* | *dbl* | *chr* |

And you can imagine that the rest of these columns would be filled out with rows of data.

Now, my *Master List* is a separate csv that I purposely created to do two things: Identify the columns I actually want to pull from the *Data Source* and what types these pulled columns should be. (As you can see, I want to set my Time of year column to be a chr, but in the *Data Source*, it is a Date)

*My question is this: How do I set the types of the columns that I pulled from the Data Source based on what I have in my Master List?*

I cannot use as.character() or as.Date() to force types since the actual data that I'm working with can contain hundreds of columns and thousands of rows. I also want this function to take in other *Data Sources* (like Dessert Data instead of Pancake Data), and I do not want to have to manually set type for each column in the *Data Source* I'm interested in (again, I might have to work with hundreds of *Data Sources* and going through and picking which columns I want and forcing their type doesn't sound fun).

I have been playing with the cols() function and trying the .default option and trying to force type that way, but it hasn't been working so far.

Any tips/advice/pointers would be really helpful! Thanks for reading.

Comment: if it should be based on column value, you can use `type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: I've tried this and played around with this function, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.